# SuiteScript: before Submit (Set sublist Value using user event script)

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I'm able to get values but not able to set sublist values in user event script beforeRecord submit. Looping through every line item to get the satisfying condition, when it come's to set value, I couldn't. am I passing wrong value or something? I'm not even receiving errors.

Please view script (edit):

`if (context.type == context.UserEventType.EDIT) {
                var salesOrderRecord = context.oldRecord;
                var formId = salesOrderRecord.getValue({
                    fieldId: 'customform'
                });
                if (formId == 150 ) {
                    var recordId = salesOrderRecord.id;
                    var lineCount = salesOrderRecord.getLineCount({
                        sublistId: 'item'
                    });
                    for(var i = 0;i < lineCount; i++){
                        var sublistItemId = salesOrderRecord.getSublistValue({
                            sublistId: 'item',
                            fieldId: 'item',
                            line: i
                        });
                if (sublistItemId != '' && sublistItemId == 29498) {
                    log.debug('Get Values',sublistItemId);      salesOrderRecord.setSublistValue('item','location',i,39);
                        }
                    }
                }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a before submit function, `context.oldRecord` is a reference to the sales order **before** it was edited by the user.  `context.newRecord` is a reference to the sales order **after** it was edited by the user but **before** it is committed to the database.

If you need to make changes, you should be updating `context.newRecord` as this will also include the changes to the record that the user just made and is the record that is going to be committed to the database.